# Is it always good to create an ID for a node?

Tags: neo4j

My data doesn't come from relational database and so it lacks a unique ID, but parsed from a variety of data sources. Is it good to create a unique sequential ID for each node?

I know Neo4j will automatically create a ID internally but I am talking about user created ID.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it’s always useful to have a unique id for nodes. It doesn’t need to be sequential necessarily. I wouldn’t rely on the ID neo4j generates for every node because it’s reusable, i.e., if you delete a node, the ID of the deleted node can be reused for a node you may create later. But all in all, it depends in your requirements.

Here you can find out how you can create UUID in neo4j:
https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/graph-updates/uuid/

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned already, Neo4j always creates an id for you. There is no need for a user defined one.